# Auto-generated edit reason being propagated from earlier revisions

Tags: bug, revisions-list, edits

Looking at [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11624518/4) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11624518/50776), the auto-generated edit reason is:

> added 24 characters in body

However, when looking at [the *entire* revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11624518/revisions), it's obvious that there are *many* more characters that were added in that revision:

[image: Revision four with more than 24 characters.]

Here's the Markdown diff as well:

[image: Markdown diff]

It would appear that 24 total characters were added in revision 2, and that edit reason was carried in revisions two through five:

[image: Copied edit reason]

Comment: If you look at revision 2, 24 is about right for `added - deleted`. Then for the next edits, that edit reason was kept in the bar since they were shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

The edit reason was copied from the previous revision(s); revs 2 through 5 all have the same edit note, which was correct for revision 2.

[image: revisions on question]

The user must have kept clicking edit close to the 5 minute grace window, so the edit reason is prefilled to the previous revision.

To reproduce: create an edit outside the grace window, so you get a generated edit note. Then edit again, within a grace period, and you'll get the edit note copied. Wait with submitting until you are outside of the grace period; so do not submit your edit for 5 minutes. A new revision is created with the pre-filled edit note.

I am guessing this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: This is obviously, incorrect (not your answer, but the system)...  Perhaps I should bring this up into the question?

Comment: I've integrated this into the main bug.

Comment: When you edit a post shortly after your previous edit, or improve a suggested edit, the edit reason is automatically filled in with the previous. Unless you type a new one, the new revision gets the same as the previous. By design, probably.

Comment: It's not a bug; if you edit a post within the grace period, but do not complete it within that grace period, a new revision is created with the old edit note.

Comment: Well then the question is, what kind of edit could you make that should have the same edit summary as the previous?

Comment: @Toomai: an edit within the grace period, so any edits made within 5 minutes of the most recent revision.

Comment: If I add 10 chars, and then add 20 chars, it shouldn't matter whether you're in the grace period or not, a default "+10" for the second edit is flat-out wrong.

Comment: @Toomai: then suggest that SE detects that an edit comment defaulted to a previously generated text, and replace it.